# Change rsvp_status on facebbok

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to let users change their rsvp_status to certain event on Facebook from my app. They have to be logged in, so I can use their access token in the request to graph API. 
But instead of changing the status I'm receiving next error:

```
04-06 19:54:42.541 14114-14114/COM.APP: save::isTokenExpired=false, response={Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'SOME_EVENT_ID' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}}
04-06 19:54:42.541 14114-14114/COM.APP: request={Request:  accessToken: {AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[public_profile, email, user_events, rsvp_event]}, graphPath: /SOME_EVENT_ID/attending, graphObject: null, httpMethod: POST, parameters: Bundle[{access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN, format=json, sdk=android}]}
```

The event does exist, it's 100%. Maybe I'm missing some permissions or what? 
Thank you.

update #1:
to post my request I use the following code:

```
GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/EVENT_FACEBOOK_ID/attending",
                null,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                GraphRequest.Callback { response: GraphResponse ->
                    // handle the result
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#events-4-4
- https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes

> Deprecated: Endpoints that return data including /feed, /posts, /comments, and the RSVP list.

If you cannot read it, you most likely cannot change it.

In other words: it´s not possible anymore.

Comment: Thank you, I've heard about restrictions, but wanted to know from other developers as well.